# CodeIgniter 4 \Config\Service::my-instance-method returns NULL on true $getShared

Tags: codeigniter, domain-driven-design, codeigniter-4

`Config\Services` is a class made to reduce huge code development on singleton. Unfortunately I have committed an error.

When repositoryFacade is got from getShared,

```
Services::repositoryFacade(Services::userRepository(), TRUE);
```

The code will fail and says:

```
Config\Services::repositoryFacade(): Return value must be of type App\Domain\Core\IRepositoryFacade, null returned
```

The following code has been set in `app/Config/Service.php`

```
public static function repositoryFacade(IRepository $repository, bool $getShared = false): IRepositoryFacade{
    if ($getShared) {
        return self::getSharedInstance('resourceFacade');
    }

    return new RepositoryFacade($repository);
}

public static function userRepository(bool $getShared = true): IRepository
{
    if ($getShared) {
        return self::getSharedInstance('userRepository');
    }

    return new UserRepository(model(UserModel::class));
}
```

`RepositoryFacade` is in infrastructure layer to serve `IRepository` domain interface one by one, while `UserRepository` is a concrete class in infrastructure layer, its duty is to let `RepositoryFacade` to perform ORM, without any touch to domain layer.

Is the getShared not useful at all? There is no error when `TRUE` value has been removed.

```
Services::repositoryFacade(Services::userRepository());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is incorrect logically.

```
Services::repositoryFacade(Services::userRepository(), TRUE);
```

Change it to below works perfectly.

```
Services::repositoryFacade(Services::userRepository(TRUE));
```

It would be more than one `RepositoryFacade` class instances can be made to serve Repository instances, such as `UserRepository`, `ProductRepository`, thus we no need to get the same instance of RepositoryFacade.

UserRepository should be unchanged all the times. Therefore we can get the same instance of UserRepository by:

```
Services::userRepository(TRUE)
```

If it is needed to use the facade with UserRepository more than once, just

```
$facade = Services::repositoryFacade(Services::userRepository(TRUE));

// use multiple times with the facade 
$result = $facade->findById(5);
if (!empty($result)) $facade->delete(5);
```